# pip install dj-database-url gives a Permission Denied Error

Tags: django, postgresql

Doing a "pip install dj-database-url" gave the following errors:

```
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 942, in prepare_files
    location = req_to_install.build_location(self.build_dir, not self.is_download)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 144, in build_location
    _make_build_dir(build_dir)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1185, in
_make_build_dir
    os.makedirs(build_dir)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/vagrant/django_projects/microblog/build'

Storing complete log in /var/lib/postgresql/.pip/pip.log
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: If you are not using virtualenv, just use `sudo` before pip.

Answer (score 3):

1. Setup virtualenv and start it up.
2. pip install Django psycopg2 south dj-database-url

Comment: thanks. i'm using vagrant/virtualbox. Do i still need virtualenv? i'm following the tutorial on gettingstartedwithdjango.com and the tutor didn't mention virtualenv. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) or run your command using `sudo`.